# Extracting members of a collection based on the contained type when the member is covariant on that type

Tags: scala, covariance

I have a case class covariant on the type of one of its member variables, which is constrained to be of a particular type:

```
case class MyCount[+T <: Identifier](
  id: T,
  count: Long,
)
```

Identifier is a sealed trait with two concrete implementations though I don't believe that this matters for the question:

```
sealed trait Identifier
case class IdentifierFoo(...) implements Identifier
case class IdentifierBar(...) implements Identifier
```

Given a collection of `MyCount[Identifier]` I want to:

1. Extract all `MyCount[IdentifierFoo]`
2. Have the resulting collection have a type `SomeCollection[MyCount[IdentifierFoo]]`

The obvious (to me) way of doing it would be as follows:

```
src.collect { case countFoo: MyCount[IdentifierFoo] => countFoo }
```

However, this fails because the type of `Count` cannot be checked accurately at runtime due to type erasure: the result (incorrectly) gets all `Count`s. I've ended up doing something quite hairy looking:

```
src.collect { count => 
  count.id match { case IdentifierFoo => { 
    count match {case countFoo: MyCount[IdentifierFoo] => countFoo }
} } }
```

This works but is ugly. I also tried matching the entire count as follows:

```
src.collect { case countFoo: MyCount[IdentifierFoo](_: IdentifierFoo, _) => countFoo }
```

...but this seems to not be valid in Scala 2.10, which is what I am constrained to.  Is there a better way of doing what I want to do?

Comment: Check this : https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2014/06/14/partitioning-by-constructor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @m-z mentions, you're better of matching on the structure than the types, but if you want the result to be of type `List[MyCount[IdentifierFoo]]`, you have to cast the values:

```
val list: List[MyCount[Identifier]] = List(MyCount(IdentifierFoo(1), 2), MyCount(IdentifierBar(2), 3), MyCount(IdentifierBar(3), 4))

 list.collect{ case countFoo @ MyCount(_ : IdentifierFoo,_) => countFoo.asInstanceOf[MyCount[IdentifierFoo]]}  
 res0: List[MyCount[IdentifierFoo]] = List(MyCount(IdentifierFoo(1),2))

 list.collect{ case countFoo @ MyCount(_ : IdentifierBar,_) =>  countFoo.asInstanceOf[MyCount[IdentifierBar]]} 
 res1: List[MyCount[IdentifierBar]] = List(MyCount(IdentifierBar(2),3), MyCount(IdentifierBar(3),4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have extractors for `IdentifierFoo` and `IdentifierBar` and know their structure, you can use them. By using extractors, you aren't matching solely on the type, so we get around type erasure.

```
list.collect { case countFoo @ MyCount(IdentifierFoo(_), _) => countFoo }
```

eg:

```
sealed trait Identifier
case class IdentifierFoo(id: Int) extends Identifier
case class IdentifierBar(id: Int) extends Identifier
case class MyCount[+T <: Identifier](id: T, count: Long)
val list = List(MyCount(IdentifierFoo(1), 2), MyCount(IdentifierBar(2), 3), MyCount(IdentifierBar(3), 4))

scala> list.collect { case countFoo @ MyCount(IdentifierFoo(_), _) => countFoo }
res142: List[MyCount[Product with Serializable with Identifier]] = List(MyCount(IdentifierFoo(1),2))

scala> list.collect { case countFoo @ MyCount(IdentifierBar(_), _) => countFoo }
res143: List[MyCount[Product with Serializable with Identifier]] = List(MyCount(IdentifierBar(2),3), MyCount(IdentifierBar(3),4))
```